# How to copy multiple projects into a single Docker container

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker

I decided to use Docker for our project's deployment, however we are having a hard time configuring docker support.
The solution itself consists of multiple projects (14 to be precise), out of which one builds the .exe file. I have added docker support to this project, so it contains the Dockerfile and Dockerignore. The solution is the backend of a web app, so no GUI is part of the code.

The problem is, that when I build and run the Docker container, it fails, because there is a path reference in the code to another project, which is not copied to the container by docker.

```
var webAppStartup = new WebAppStartup(new 
    AutofacDependencyContainerFactory().Create(AddDependencies),
        new HostingEnvironment
        {
            EnvironmentName = EnvironmentName.Development
        }, 
        Path.GetFullPath(@"../MyOtherProject/"));
```

I tried to COPY both projects using the Dockerfile by moving the file one level upper in the directory tree, however if I try to COPY something which is not in the dockerfile's immediate context, Docker throws an error, stating that I can only copy files within the build context.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-MyProject/obj/Docker/publish} .
COPY ${source:-MyOtherProject/obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\app\\MyProject.exe"]
```

How can I copy multiple projects (or the whole solution?) to a docker container, or is there any workaround for this kind of problem? I am absolutely new to Docker, and my knowledge of how Docker builds and runs images and containers is superficial at best.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure ... in my solution have 2 project to But try something like this.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-stretch AS publish
```

First create new

```
WORKDIR /src/
COPY ./ .
```

set work directory and coppy

```
RUN dotnet publish --output /src/out
```

To publish all project in solution is already add reference and create new docker

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-stretch
```

and copy from previous publish to new docker

```
COPY --from=publish /src/out .
```

Full code below
https://github.com/uopeydel/readme.txt/blob/master/Readme.Web/Readme.Web/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Each container one project,

but if your `container` is a WebServer like `IIS`, `Apache` and other you can 
copy your project folder in your Dockerized WebServer.

In this case you have one container with multiple application.

For examplie, you have 3 or more project for IIS Server or other platform like the follow image:

[image]

obviously the projects must have same platform.

When you build and excecute the project is moved into the same container and exceuted by only WebServer.

In the Docker Context you have not a classical `PATH` becouse you work in a difference environment.

Start your test with simple project, remeber KISS KEEP IT SIMPLE SIMPLE :-)